# How to apply the same filter to each dataframe in a list of dataframes

Tags: r

How to apply the same filter to each dataframe in a list of dataframes.

For example, if I want to apply a mutation like so:

```
test_df <- test_df %>% filter(id != 0)
```

On a list of dataframes

Comment: please try something, and if it doesn't work, post what you tried and the incorrect result it gave.

Comment: `lapply` is useful here, or (imho) `purrr`'s `map`-function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example with the `iris` data frame and a slight modification of it to make a list of 2 slightly different data frames which have the same column names. Then I apply a specific filter (in this case one that makes sense in the context of the `iris` data frame) to return either a list of data frames or one concatenated data frame (depends on what kind of result you would like to have)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Petal.Length = Petal.Length*2)

dfs <- list(iris, iris2)

filtering <- function(df){
  df %>% 
    filter(Petal.Length > 3)
}

list_result <- purrr::map(dfs, filtering) # or
df_result <- purrr::map_df(dfs, filtering)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

#create your list of Data Frames and assign it to a value
myListOfDataframes 

#write a function for your list to loop through
filterDataframeFunction <- function(){
  filter(id != 0)
}

#use the map function to send your list to your function
map(myListOfDataframes, filterDataframeFunction)
```

Comment: You don't have to define the `filterDataframeFunction`. Either `map(mylist, filter, id != 0)` or `map(mylist, ~ filter(., id != 0))` will do.